# Docker development and manage remote machine

Tags: linux, windows, docker, intellij-idea, putty

We are developing an application using 3 docker containers. The development is done under a windows environnement on which  we are getting issues preventing the containers run.
Those issues seems to be related to running the container under windows environnement.

As a workaround we are thinking about is to configure a remote server on intellij that access a linux remote virtual machine.
Please note we access the VM using putty and execute the application the containers runs successfully.

So my question here is it possible to continue the development using that workaround? all we need is having all containers running and launch and visualise application interfaces on  Windows

Comment: You'd have one step fewer if you ran the Linux VM locally (maybe using Vagrant?), and one step fewer still if you directly ran Linux on the desktop.

Comment: I second David's comment - Vagrant running ubuntu (or whatever your target linux is), with docker on it is the way to go for development on Windows.

Comment: but why should I use Vagrant instead of just VirtualBox?  what benefits specifically does Vagrant offer over VirtualBox when it's about a development of a docker multi container application?